# What are some architecture patterns to consider when building a REST api sync application?

Tags: rest, design-patterns, architecture

#### TLDR;

We're syncing data by calling a third party api, mapping the data and posting to a destination api.
We are integrating more third parties down the line.
What are some architectural patterns to consider for this kind of software?

---

#### The Details

I'm on a team that builds a solution that sync data from one REST Api to another.
We're currently only syncing from one source, to one destination. More sources will be implemented.

We started building an Onion Architecture solution, and it works just fine.
However:

- Since we only want to sync (put or post) new data, we have to call the destination api first to see what we already have. This happens in the infrastructure layer of the application.
- Then we call the source api, and filter it so we only have new or updated data (also in infrastructure layer)
- The data is converted from third party objects to core objects (also in infrastructure layer)
- Then it's converted to the destination objects, and sendt to the destination api (also in infrastructure layer)

<sub>You might see where this is going..</sub>

Most data processing happens in infrastructure layer, because the core layer is independent of everything (projects, nugets, etc.). If we were to follow the Onion pattern completely, we would process in Core, but that means that we have to do more mapping before comparing data.

We all feel that a lot of what exists in the core layer, are unnecessary, since we basically just map to core objects and then map straight to the infrastructure objects.

Do you have any suggestions to other architectures we should concider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software architecture is a combination of science, engineering, art, and craft. The goal is to define an overall conceptual model for a system that enables developers and maintainers to respond nimbly to changes in requirements or circumstances.

As Robert C. Martin put it (I think), good software architecture is about making the right decisions about those things that are difficult to change in the future. Many things in a code base are easy to change, and we shouldn't obsess about those. The things that are hard to change are decisions about language, platform, framework, technologies applied (e.g. which database to use, HTTP vs. Protocol Buffers, etc.), synchronous vs. asynchronous, ACID vs. eventually consistent, etc.

In other words, you first analyse the problem and then pick an architecture that matches.

Why pick the Onion architecture for a problem as described above?

The point about that architecture ([also known as Ports and Adapters, or Hexagonal architecture](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same)) is to protect the Domain Model from implementation details (in other words, the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)).

According to the description in the OP, there's no business logic to speak of. Instead, it sounds like an [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) job. Pick an architecture suitable for that task.

It can be as simple as a [Transaction Script](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html) or something more involved.

A couple of years ago one of my clients needed to implement something similar, and in that particular context, we agreed that what made most sense was an eventually consistent asynchronous daemon based on the [pipes and filters architecture](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com) with a bit of CQRS thrown in for good measure.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! 

We picked onion because it was central to our education. Our mentor suggested that we did it this way and move to whatever we felt was better after, so this is part of the experience I guess.. 

But anyways, we will look into various approaches to ETL and look into the links you posted. Thanks again!